# Cannot encrypt files in windows 10 home (option is greyed out)

Tags: encryption, windows-registry, administrator

When I right click a file, go to properties, general, advanced the option to encrypt a file is greyed out even if I'm admin. I also checked in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" and the key "NtfsDisableEncryption" and is alredy set to 0. Is there a way to enable it or the problem is that I have a home version of windows 10? Because microsoft in [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/encrypt-decrypt-folder-file#1TC=windows-7) doesn't specify it.

Comment: According to this support thread from Microsoft, this may not be available in the Home edition (and BitLocker is only for Pro): http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/encryption-in-windows-10-home/1c5a374e-ab00-4ebc-932d-6420063e125b?auth=1

Comment: Bitlocker and EFS is a feature of Windows 10 Professional and above.  Device encryption is a feature of both Home and Professional on supported devices, it's hardware dependent, research how to enable it if your device supports it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows encryption features are typically only available for professional and enterprise editions, plus (depending on who you ask) there are more secure open source alternatives like Veracrypt, which is based on the discontinued Truecrypt.